# tensorflow: tensor to ndarray conversion doesn't work - python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am working on Tensorflow CNN Model and changed according to my scenario. Previously same code worked well on MNIST dataset but now, after feeding my own dataset a placeholder `y_true` for labels is causing problem. Code snippet:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float",shape=[88, 128])
y_true = tf.placeholder("float",shape=[None, 3])
```

`y_true` in the session gets me error. Code snippet:

```
sess.run(train,feed_dict={x:batch_x, y_true:batch_y,hold_prob:0.5})
```

Error:

```
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object.
Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, 
numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.
```

I casted it to `numpy array` via `y = np.array(y_true)` and tweaked the statement according to `y` but again error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Tried `y_true.eval(session = my_sess)` as suggested here on stackoverflow but again error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
'Placeholder_4' with dtype float and shape [?,3]
```

Any idea? What's wrong here and how to cast/convert it to suitable format.
Additional info:

```
batch_x = batch of 50 images (total 200K), 88x128 single channel
batch_y = labels (string) same batch as above
```

Comment: Did you get `batch_x` and `batch_y` from the dataset API? Show the code

Answer (score 0):

```
batch_y = labels (string) same batch as above`enter
```

If this means that your labels are strings, that might be the cause of the error because placeholders delcared as floats.

Otherwise, recheck your datatypes and dimensions.

Comment: I know this may cause the issue. That's why I am asking for help. Any code snippet or any link. Basically, I am testing this code on a folder containing 3 subfolders each having some images. I'm using these folders as labels for corresponding images. That's why `string`. Any help would be appreciated to work around.

Comment: You could install keras on top of tensorflow and it'll simplify a lot of these work for you. See flow_from_directory(directory) in keras. Or google around for one hot encoding and looping through directory.

Comment: [Directory iterator](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py)  here might be of help.